# Magento2 - How to avoid/ignore PHP Fatal Errors while running magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am developing a Magento 2 Module that need to reference external packages (through composer).

I added a package in `require` section inside `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
  "php": "~7.3.11",
  "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"
}
```

Then ran `composer update` to load packages into `vendor` folder

Then ran `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, but an error is thrown like this:

PHP Fatal error:

> Trait 'Evenement\EventEmitterTrait' not found in 
>       /app/code///vendor/evenement/evenement/src/Evenement/EventEmitter.php
>   on line 18

**Question is**: is there a way to ignore or avoid errors from `vendor` folder?

I could have solved the error manually to let compilation complete, but the problem is this solution need to be repeated each time the module's repo is cloned or if the `vendor` folder is deleted then `composer update/install` is run again.

Comment: You can compile specific module by this way : https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-run-setupdicompile-for-specific-module/

Comment: @RohanHapani Thanks for your advice, the problem in my case is that errors come from my module's vendor folder e.g. <magento>/app/code/<vendor>/<module>/vendor/, so I still need to fix the errors or find a workaround

Answer (score 0):

For reasons like this, I do not support or use composer.

Looks like you did a composer install and are missing a source file required for the module to properly be compiled. Try finding the missing resource/file. 
git is usually very helpful in identifying the missing files.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I installed Magento using Composer, and I actually ended up fixing all the errors those came in my way.